# How to sequence app script for large data copying which takes more than 5 mins time?

Tags: google-apps-script, sequence, large-data

My code is simple in google sheet but large data handling takes a longer time.

I have 8 data(1 data have Rows=1750,columns=64) that I want to copy to the same sheet at other columns.
There are recorddata1 to recorddata8 functions.

```
function recorddata1() {

var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Analysis").getSheetValues(3,2,1750,64);
var pastedata = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Analysis");
pastedata.getRange(3,3,1750,64).setValues(data);

}
```

Due to the larger data size, one function takes more than 2 mins (average). if I add all 8 functions in a single function, it exceeds the max time limit of 5mins. It results in the non-execution of a few functions within the time limit.
Request you to kindly suggest from following or guide me resolve this issue.

1. Is it possible to copy such large data in 5 mins? (Rows=1750,columns=64)*8 such data having numbers.
2. Is it possible to set the sequence of data1 (in 5 mins) after data2(in another 5 min) and so on.
3. Is it possible if all 8 data functions can be simultaneously run at the same time?
4. Using a single trigger, I can execute one-after-one data functions?

Please guide me to resolve my problem.

I tried to execute functions in a single function but it does not work and exceeded time limit of 5 mins.
I could not find the option to sequentially execute functions one after another.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot know `all 8 data functions`, how about using Sheets API? When Sheets API is used instead of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp), the process cost can be reduced. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) But, I cannot know the detail of `all 8 data functions`. So, I cannot propose a sample script. I apologize for this. By the way, I cannot understand `2. Is it possible to set the sequence of data1 (in 5 mins) after data2(in another 5 min) and so on.` and `4. Using a single trigger, I can execute one-after-one data functions?`.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). The bad performance you describe may be caused by something else in the spreadsheet. See [these optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339?msgid=102278707).

Comment: if you do `getSheetValues(3,2,1750,64)` and then `getRange(3,3,1750,64).setValues()` you're erasing most of the previous data right (63 cols of the previous range get replaced)